# WCF Timeout exception on streaming big files

Tags: wcf, uwp, streaming

I'm currently working on a WCF streaming service. So far everything works great for files up to 2 GB. I've set up the service as a streaming service and I am chunking the files on my own on 5 MB chunks. However, files bigger than 2 GB (somewhere there is the threshold) i always get an `InvalidOperationException`with the message `Timeouts are not supported on this stream.` I'm not really sure why and where this exception is thrown. It don't think this is a server side problem because every request should be the same and most of them work. But the exceptions comes from the generated proxy. So the source is `System.Private.ServiceModel`

Stack trace:

```
at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.SendAsyncResult.End(SendAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.EndCall(String action, Object[] outs, IAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.TaskCreator.<>c__DisplayClass0.<CreateGenericTask>b__1(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Company.OurApp.App.DataService.BaseFile.<DownloadItem>d__59.MoveNext()
```

Here is my server implementaion:

```
var response = new GetFileResponse();
                using (var impersonation = new Impersonation(request.Domain, request.Username, request.Password))
                {
                    using (Stream fStream = File.OpenRead(request.FullFilePath))
                    {
                        fStream.Seek(request.FilePart * request.FilePartSize, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                        BinaryReader bStream = new BinaryReader(fStream);
                        var filePart = bStream.ReadBytes(request.FilePartSize);

                        using (Stream mStream = new MemoryStream(filePart))
                        {
                            response.FileByteStream = mStream;
                            return response;
                        }
                    }
                }
```

The GetFileResponse looks like this:

```
[MessageContract]
public class GetFileResponse
{
    [MessageBodyMember(Order = 1)]
    public Stream FileByteStream { get; set; }
}
```

This is how the client handles the download (UWP App):

```
using (Stream f = await StorageFile.OpenStreamForWriteAsync())
                {
                    //Cancelation area - after every async operation if possilble
                    for (int i = 0; i < sections; i++)
                    {
                        token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                        var response = await client.GetFilePartAsync(request.ConnectionPassword, request.Domain, i, FilePartSize, FullPath, request.Password, request.Username);
                        token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                        DownloadProgress = response.FileByteStream.Length;

                        f.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.End);
                        await f.WriteAsync(response.FileByteStream, 0, response.FileByteStream.Length);
                        await f.FlushAsync();
                    }
                }
```

And here is the service web.config:

```
 <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="HttpsServiceBehaviour"
               name="Company.OurApp.TransportService.DataService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="streamedBinding" contract="Company.OurAppTransportService.IDataService">
        </endpoint>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="HttpsServiceBehaviour">
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="streamedBinding" transferMode="Streamed" closeTimeout="10:00:00">
          <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
```

When generating the client proxy, i set some timeouts but that didn't change anything:

```
public DataServiceClient GetDataServiceClient(string endpoint = null)
        {
            var useEndpoint = String.IsNullOrEmpty(endpoint) ? Configuration.ConfigService : endpoint;

            System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpBinding result = new System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpBinding();
            result.MaxBufferSize = int.MaxValue;
            result.ReaderQuotas = System.Xml.XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas.Max;
            result.MaxReceivedMessageSize = int.MaxValue;
            result.AllowCookies = true;
            result.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = System.ServiceModel.HttpClientCredentialType.Windows;

            //TODO Try to work with timeouts for larges files?
            result.SendTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
            result.ReceiveTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
            result.OpenTimeout = TimeSpan.MaxValue;


            if (useEndpoint.ToLower().StartsWith("https://"))
                result.Security.Mode = System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport;
            else
                result.Security.Mode = System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportCredentialOnly;

            var client = new DataServiceClient(result, new System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress(String.Concat(useEndpoint, fixedEndpointSuffix)));
            client.ClientCredentials.Windows.AllowedImpersonationLevel = System.Security.Principal.TokenImpersonationLevel.Impersonation;

            if (AppState.IsLoggedIn)
            {
                client.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.UserName = $@"{AppState.Domain}\{AppState.User}";
                client.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.Password = AppState.Password;
            }

            return client;
        }
```

Any idea where and why the exception is thrown? Server? Client? Is it coming from the stream? Help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Is there a way to push this? :) Just in case it got lost - i'm still facing the error und would appreciate some help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For everybody else facing the same problem. I got it solved by analyzing the exceptions with the [WCF TraceViewer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/service-trace-viewer-tool-svctraceviewer-exe). I also called the Service from a console application to be sure it's not a UWP problem. The problem was that I closed the streams before the response could reach the client.

Broken implementation:

```
var response = new GetFileResponse();
            using (var impersonation = new Impersonation(request.Domain, request.Username, request.Password))
            {
                using (Stream fStream = File.OpenRead(request.FullFilePath))
                {
                    fStream.Seek(request.FilePart * request.FilePartSize, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                    BinaryReader bStream = new BinaryReader(fStream);
                    var filePart = bStream.ReadBytes(request.FilePartSize);

                    using (Stream mStream = new MemoryStream(filePart))
                    {
                        response.FileByteStream = mStream;
                        return response;
                    }
                }
            }
```

This one fixed it for me:

```
Stream fStream = File.OpenRead(request.FullFilePath);

                long offset = request.FilePart * request.FilePartSize;
                fStream.Seek(offset, SeekOrigin.Begin);

                BinaryReader bStream = new BinaryReader(fStream);
                var filePart = bStream.ReadBytes((int)request.FilePartSize);

                Stream mStream = new MemoryStream(filePart);

                response.FileByteStream = mStream;
                return response;
```

Hope it helps!